# Determine the permutation matrix of a permutation in $S_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image]

What does cycle and $M=M_c$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

A [cycle (or a *cyclic permutation*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) $c$ is a specific kind of permutation where each element is moved one place to the side, and then the element at the end is moved to the beginning. $M_c$ is the corresponding [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). It has $1$ in all entries just below the main diagonal, a $1$ in the top right corner, and otherwise $0$ everywhere (assuming that $c$ permutes all the elements of our set)

Comment: can you help me with the next 3 questions ? How to compute char?